js rewrite prototype.call, but why did "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" appear
Function.prototype.call = function(point,...arg){
    console.log('ok');
    const key = Symbol('key')
    point[key] = this
    const data = point[key](...arg)
    delete point[key]
    return data
}
function fn(a,b){
    this.sum = a+b
    return a + b
}
const obj = {}
const data = fn.call(obj,3,4)
console.log(data);
console.log(obj);

node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:149
  if (stdout) return stdout;
  ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:149:3)  
    at console.get (node:internal/console/constructor:214:42)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:340:50)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:379:61)
    at Function.call (C:\Users\xyk\Desktop\my study\nodejs\node.js中级\23重写call函数.js:2:13)
    at new WriteStream (node:tty:96:14)
    at createWritableStdioStream (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:53:16)      
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:150:12) 
    at console.get (node:internal/console/constructor:214:42)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:340:50)

Node.js v20.12.1

But if you change "prototype.call" to "prototype.Mycall", this problem will not occur
Function.prototype.Mycall = function(point,...arg){
    console.log('ok');
    const key = Symbol('key')
    point[key] = this
    const data = point[key](...arg)
    delete point[key]
    return data
}
function fn(a,b){
    this.sum = a+b
    return a + b
}
const obj = {}
const data = fn.Mycall(obj,3,4)
console.log(data);
console.log(obj);

ok
7
{ sum: 7 }

This question really confuses me
if I delete "console.log()",the problem will disappear. But I want say, for the case of "prototype. Mycall", even if there is "console. log()", no error will be reported

Holy crow don't try to do better than what the browser ships with when it comes to stuff like call - its so fundamental, just don't mess with it.

The nodejs console.log implementation uses .call(). Your Function.prototype.call implementation uses console.log(). This means mutual recursion, and causes a stack overflow since there is no base case.
So: don't mess with builtins!

Exactly! Yeah, the same code should work without any issue if you try it in a fresh browser tab console. But when it comes to node, they are using .call somewhere in the process and more methods like process.stdout.write etc.
